# Can't round to significant figures without floating point errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, rounding, significant-digits

I'm populating a DataGridView with a set of data with numbers of varying size. The source of the data is a text file which has numbers with very big precision, but the precision needn't be that huge. For display purposes, 4 significant figures should be enough

Text file contains four tab-delimited columns with numbers:

> 1002.02    0.00289800321   0.000358283985  0.12363132786178
>   998.76  0.00302583165   0.000374897063  0.123898850420181
>   995.41  0.0031501574    0.000391117879  0.124158202063173
>   ...

But I would want to cut down on the digits when shown in the grid. Here are the values with 4 significant digits

> 1002   0.002898    0.0003583   0.1236
>   998.8   0.003026    0.0003749   0.1239
>   995.4   0.00315 0.0003911   0.1242
>   ...

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rounding_and_decimal_places) for the formula

[image]
[image]

which is done in VB. There is a class with the values in properties, and when the properties are gotten, the rounding is performed

```vb
Private Shared ReadOnly _significantDigits As Integer = 3
Private _Ratio As Double
Public Property Ratio As Double ' all the properties look like this
    Get
        Return round(_Ratio)
    End Get
    Set
        _Ratio = Value
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Function round(value As Double) As Double
    Dim n = Math.Round(Math.Log10(value) + 1 - _significantDigits )
    Return (10 ^ n) * Math.Round(Math.Abs(value) / (10 ^ n))
    ' Return value
End Function
```

The grid has the right number of significant digits, but shows that some of the resulting values include floating point errors

[image]

If the value is returned directly (without using the `round` function), I have no floating point errors on the grid, but the numbers have too many significant digits.

[image]

The binding is simply this c#

```cs
this.CalibrationFileTextDataGridView.DataSource = _ownedWavelengthCalibration.CalibrationDatas.ToList()
```

So what's an effective way to round to significant digits, while discarding floating point errors, considering the number of decimal places in the final values is not the same across all columns? I don't want to use scientific notation because 1. it is unnecessary for the Wavelength column, and 2. it makes the columns unnecessarily wide.

Answers and comments in c# or vb are both fine.

Comment: Use the Decimal data type?

Comment: 10 ^ n will only have a non-NaN result for negative values of n when n is an integer.  Right now it is Double and will have a value like -1.9999...99424454.  These floating point precision problems are creepy enough to consider using String.Format() and String.TrimEnd().  These tables do get more readable to human eyes when the number of digits in the fraction are consistent.

Comment: @GSerg I need a null/NaN because one of either PowerRx or PowerTx will always be absent and I need to reflect that in the display, hence the NaN in the grid. Decimal is rendering as 0, however. I tried decimal? and 0 is still shown. Other than that the rounding errors are gone and everything else looks great.

Comment: @HansPassant The wavelength is in the 875 - 1000 nm range and wouldn't look great with 6 digits after the decimal - and I'm not about to display μm or mm :) . I had considered using string formatting too. Might be easier to just format a number of digits based on the log10. I'll try that.

Comment: No, same number of digits per column, not the entire table.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I had misunderstood. Yes I agree but the rounding errors are much more disagreeable to the eye. I will address that next.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncating you could use the `Round` method and then convert the result to `decimal`.
Try the following:

```
var number = 0.000391117879D;
var number2 = 998.76D;


var roundedNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(RoundToSignificantDigits(number, 4));
var roundedNumber2 = Convert.ToDecimal(RoundToSignificantDigits(number2, 4));

double RoundToSignificantDigits(double d, int digits)
{
   if (d == 0)
      return 0;

   var scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1);
   return scale * Math.Round(d / scale, digits);
}
```

I know it's in C#, but it should be quite easy to convert to VB.

Comment: This causes 978.64 to display as 978.6000, rounding to sig-figs while displaying zeros suggesting they are significant.

Comment: In that case I'm certain you need 5 sig figs instead?

Comment: 978.6000 has 7 sig-figs. 978.64 has 5 but represented with 7 is 978.6400. For one, it's not setting 4 sig-figs, and secondly it's discarding 0.04. But anyway my function handles it well already and using Decimal is really all I need to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're not being consistent. You want 998.76 to be displayed as 998.7, but 978.64 as 978.64?

Comment: 978.6000 has 7 sig-figs, that's the point. If you can get rid of the zeros then it might work. I'm not sure if I want 4 or 5 sig figs but that should be configurable anyway

Comment: So you're okay with the solution, it's just the zeroes at the end you want to get rid of?

Comment: The simpler solution is to just replace Double with Decimal in my own code.